# Basic SQL CURRENT_TIME() query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a column having date & time. I have to get all the rows which have the date and time before the current time. So i have written the following

```
SELECT * FROM G_CARD_SCHEDULE WHERE TIME_TO_BE_SENT < CURRENT_TIME()
```

And the table has the following column

> TIME_TO_BE_SENT = 2010-10-08 00:57:50

But still 0 rows are returned by the SQL, what is wrong?

Comment: what is the datatype of TIME_TO_BE_SENT ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CURRENT_TIME() returns only the time, not the date and time.

> Returns the current time as a value in 'HH:MM:SS'

Try with `NOW()`. See the manual section [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Sql engines have different function names for current time
For My-sql loook at the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can use NOW() and in sql you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() for this format

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use current_date() as well...since current_time does what it seems to do...return the current time and only the time.

Another option is now() which returns both date and time.